# Node.js Addon cannot convert arguments

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm making *String Transformation library* using [Node.js c++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/addons.html).

I know I can easily make this library with JavaScript, but I need to do it with [Node.js c++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/addons.html).

According to this answer [Converting from v8::Arguments to C++ Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476145/converting-from-v8arguments-to-c-types?noredirect=1&lq=1). I have checked [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476145/converting-from-v8arguments-to-c-types#answer-10255816) but its returns the same error

**So I declared `void uppercase` to transform some String to Uppercase.**

> **But there is an Error**
>
> ```
> D:\transformer\src\transformer.cc(30): error C2664: 'std::string Transformation::toUpperCase(std::string)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Local<v8::String>' to 'std::string'  [D:\transformer\build\transformer.vcxproj]
> ```

I tried to solve that but failed because I'm new to c++ addons. I also checked that error code [C2664](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd.aspx) which doesn't solve my problem.

#### transformer.cc

```
// transformer.cc
#include <node.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace v8;
using namespace std;

namespace Transformations {

    string toUpperCase(string str) {
        transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
        return str;
    }

}

namespace Transformer {

    void uppercase(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
        Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        
        Local<String> str = Local<String>::Cast(args[0]);

        if(!args[0]->IsString()) {
            isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong arguments")));
            return;
        }

        args.GetReturnValue().Set(Transformations::toUpperCase(str));
    }

    void lowercase(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) { }

    void capitalize(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) { }

    void reverse(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) { }

    void init(Local<Object> exports) {
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "uppercase", uppercase);
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "lowercase", lowercase);
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "capitalize", capitalize);
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "reverse", reverse);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(transformer, init)

}
```

#### test.js

```
const transformer = require('bindings')('transformer');

console.log(transformer.uppercase("Dinindu"));
```

---

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476145/converting-from-v8arguments-to-c-types

Comment: @BaummitAugen I checked that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476145/converting-from-v8arguments-to-c-types#answer-10255816 answer. But it also return same error. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @BaummitAugen Could your make answer for this please?

Comment: Nope, I don't know the technology. That link was my best guess I got from google.

Comment: It seems like an ambeguty issue with string maybe define the parameter with the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here, The [Native Abstractions](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) (nan) solved my problem.

**1. First add this code to the `binding.gyp` file under the targets**

```
"include_dirs" : ["<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"]
```

**2. After installing [nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan), import it by adding this line at the head of `transformer.cc`**

```
#include <nan.h>
```

**3. Now, change our `uppercase` function a bit:**

```
void uppercase(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    v8::String::Utf8Value value(args[0]->ToString());
    std::string name = std::string(*value);
    std::string uppercased_name = Transformations::toUpperCase(name);

    if(!args[0]->IsString()) {
        isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong arguments")));
        return;
    }

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New(uppercased_name).ToLocalChecked());
}
```